# Cannot link html page to seperate .js page?

Tags: jquery, html

this is probably extremely basic but im having a nightmare. I want to be able to hide text on my webpage and show it/hide it again when a button is clicked.

However I cannot even seem to link my html page to my javascript page (they have to be on separate pages for school). I am trying initially to just hide the text, but cant even do that so I presume the pages are not linking. Sorry if this is a stupid question I just am getting no where. Would love some help! thanks!

```
<head>
<title>Saffron Physiotherapy Dublin - Our Team</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div id="textbehindbutton"><p>text to be hidden.....</p></div>
<div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
```

jQuery code is as:

```
$("#textbehindbutton").hide();
```

Comment: Try enabling jQuery using this: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I usually import the jquery-1.11.1.min.js file instead. Would that maybe help?

Comment: @conor.ob What folder is the JavaScript file in? Is it at the same level as your HTML doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give this code a try

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

After that, the jQuery code **should** look like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#textbehindbutton").hide();
});
```

I really am getting some feeling that you're not using the `$(document).ready(function () { .. });` function call the jQuery events.

jQuery really needs to have that in order to work.

Comment: yes, that works now, thanks for your help! now to figure out how to show and hide it with a button! cheers

Comment: @conor.ob here you go.. one liner: `$(function(){ $('.button').click(function() { $('#text').toggle(); }); });` (http://jsfiddle.net/7Zvug/5/)

Comment: brilliant, really appreciate it!